# encrypt and decrypt outpus symbols

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, cryptography

Myself and a colleague are trying to produce a program that allows us to encrypt and decrypt text using alphabetic values of two words:

1. **a keyword** (chosen by the user)
2. a **source word** to encrypt/ decrypt (chosen by user too)

But for some reason when we run the program we can get as far as outputting an encrypted/decrypted answer, however the answer is a text:

```
Ƥ˧Щ
```

Here is our code:

```
def encryptfunction():
    result = ""
    addedup = 0
    for letter in wordtoencrypt:
        for letter2 in keyword:
            addedup = addedup + ord(letter2)
        result = result + chr(ord(letter) + addedup)
    return result

def decryptfunction():    
    result = ""
    addedup = 0
    for letter in wordtoencrypt:
        for letter2 in keyword:
            addedup = addedup + ord(letter2)
        result = result + chr(ord(letter) - addedup)
    return result

wordtoencrypt = input("Enter the word to encrypt:")
keyword = input("Enter the keyword:")
encrypt = int(input("encrypt(1) or decrypt(0)"))

if encrypt == 1:
    print(encryptfunction())
else:
    print(decryptfunction())
```

We have no idea why this happens and would much appreciate if someone could help us fix this.

Comment: You can try printing intermediate values, but it appears that string and numbers are mixed up in the additions.

Comment: The ASCII character set has 256 characters. Some of them are letters, others are symbols. If you add the character codes of two English letters, the character you will get as a result will be a symbol. What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: how do I fix the ascii??

Comment: What do you mean by "fix the ascii"? The ASCII character set is not broken. What results do you expect to get?

Comment: `result = result + chr((ord(letter) + addedup) % 256)` to stay in range of ascii characters

Answer (score 0):

You may try typecasting addedup and result variables.